# Why busybox grep stop working?

Tags: android, terminal, grep, busybox

From the first time I installed busybox pro version.apk it seems working.

Until then I run with or without "su" this command below:

```
busybox grep -ri "podnet" /
```

and then my terminal stop working. It is not hang or nor not responding either.

But i wonder why did the busybox grep seems not working, it doesn't give any output at all. The cursor seems stop at the beginning of the newline just like that.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Using the -r (recursive) option and providing the file path as root (/) you have asked grep to search all files on all mounted file systems for the pattern "podnet".  If you have networked drives, that could be a huge search.

You should first consider providing a more specific path that root (/).  Another option for long running commands is to run the command in the background and redirect output to a file.

For example:

$ grep -ri "podnet" /home >/tmp/podnet.lst &

Finally, if you enter a Linux command and wish to stop it, you have two options.  Enter Cntl-C to abort the command, or Cntl-Z to suspend it.